# Trying to connect to an FTP server from Azure App service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-vm

I am trying to upload/download some files from Azure VM directly through a Azure App service, but the app returns this error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments.

I am using blazor and this is the code from the that I use to upload:

```
{
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dir/file.conf");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.UsePassive = false;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");

    // convert contents to byte.
    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str); ;

    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    }

    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Upload File Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");
    }
}
```

If I do try from my PC it works properly.

Comment: can you check whether the port is open and the outbound connection is successful for FTP? Try it by running the command `tcpping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21` where xx.xxx is your ftp domain and 21 is the ftp port

Comment: It is, I can connect through terminal/cmd, but when I deploy the app to azure I got the error.

Also the app works properly from my computer, it downloads and uploads correctly, the problem is once deployed.

Comment: So you saying running the above command in the azure kudo console is successful?

Comment: Ok, I have checked again in the console (sorry, didn't know what you meant at first), and I got a Time Out with tcpping

Comment: so its looks like from azure web app your ftp connection is not established .Thats why you are getting the error. From our local machine if you do the `telnet xx.xxx.x 21` it will work because the connection is established properly. So the issue is happening only from azure app due to the network restriction

Comment: @Jayendran is there any solution for this, i am having same issue like i am able to connect to ftp when i run application locally but not able to connect from azure web app. it says `Unable to connect to the remote server`

Answer (score 0):

- There could be several reasons for the FTP issue, the exact error message may provide some pointers.
- Azure App Service supports connecting via both Active and Passive mode. Passive mode is preferred because your deployment machines are usually behind a firewall.
- If you set UsePassive to false, then you need to make sure that the port for the command channel is open (i.e., you need to define endpoints and access rules). Unless there is a good reason to not use passive, you are far better off using passive.
- Refer this document for more information:
  [Deploy your app to Azure App Service using FTP/S](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=portal#get-ftp-connection-information)
- You can also copy files directly from Kudu console to local:
  http://yourwebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/  (Add'scm' to the default WebApps mentioned above)
- Go to the cmd button and look in the site/wwwroot folder for your project files.
- You could also use VS team explorer to clone the WebApp from Azure App Service to your local Visual Studio (VS).